# Reuse View group with small variety

Tags: android

I'm new to android app programming and I'm curious about reusing a layout that contains a few views with small differences.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/Font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/lbl_graph_last" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last"
            style="@style/Font"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I need to use this layout with the 2 textviews inside multiple times with the only differences: the text in the first TextView `android:text="@string/lbl_graph_last"` and I also need to change the text of the second TextView programmatically (I'm planning on using the id for that, but I'm open for better suggestions).

Comment: You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) to create your own custom view. Then you can easily use it anywhere.

Comment: You can also use recycler view if you data is dynamic and you don't know beforehand how many of these layout will be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom view and then use it anywhere like a regular view in xml. Follow this [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) for more details.

1. Create a layout for the custom view. Make sure that root tag for this layout is `<merge>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_second"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

2. Define what properties you want to make configurable, and then define them in a `attrs.xml` file. You can create `attrs.xml` file inside your `values` folder.

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="text_first" format="string" />
        <attr name="text_second" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

3. Create your custom view

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout{
    private TextView textFirst, textSecond;

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (context == null || attrs == null)
            return;
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomView, 0, 0);
        String first = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomView_text_first);
        String last = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomView_text_second);
        a.recycle();
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.layout_custom_view, this);
        textFirst = findViewById(R.id.text_first);
        textSecond = findViewById(R.id.text_second);
        textFirst.setText(first);
        textSecond.setText(last);
    }
    
    // you can expose methods for attributes you want to set programatically
    public void setSecondText(String text) {
        textSecond.setText(text);
    }
}
```

4. Use your custom view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">


    <com.example.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/top_custom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:text_first="Hi..."/>

</LinearLayout>
```

5. Change attributes programatically

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMain2Binding binding = ActivityMain2Binding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        CustomView customView = binding.topCustomView;
        customView.setSecondText("How are you?");
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

[image]